# jQuery Conflict with mousewheel

Tags: jquery, colorbox, timeline

I'm a designer doing a commemoration project for Red Cross Australia's 2004 Tsunami clean up efforts. The project is a timeline to commemorate all the work that has been done for the last few years.

**Note: As a first time user I wasn't allowed to include more than 1 link, so I'm sorry for all the urls I have pasted in.**

I'm using two jquery plugins to create the timeline:

This horizontal scroll plugin from [JQuery for designers](http://www.jqueryfordesigners.com/fun-with-overflows/)

See [here](http://www.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/scrollable-timelines.html) for a direct link to the demo timeline-

I have also used the [Colorbox](http://www.colorpowered.com/colorbox/) jquery plugin for displaying pictures and media

There is functionality on the timeline for users to click and drag or use the mouse scroll wheel.

I have an issue where the mouse scroll wheel doesn't work after I add the colorbox code to the page. The timeline works fine on its own as does colorbox, its just when they are added together.

As a designer primarily, I don’t know how to fix the issue, but I have narrowed down the focus to some sort of conflict when the jquery.min.js file is linked to for the colorbox plugin. The mouse wheel scrolling returns if I remove the link to this js in the head.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked through my issue by simply placing the link to the jquery.js file after the jquery.min.js files.

I think the jquery.min.js file was reseting a value that was set by the jquery.js file.

By placing the call to this file afterwards the value doesn't get reset.